# dynamic creation of html elements using php and doing pagination using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, getelementbyid, dynamically-generated

I am creating a element dynamically in html and want to use it in a javascript function by referring to its ID. But as its ID is dynamically generated using PHP , so how do i pass it to the javascript function into **getElementById**?

Actually , i am trying to do pagination using javascript. I have displayed Page No.s, and put HREF on them, but onclick function am stuck up? Please help. My code is as below:

```
<?php
echo 'Page';

while($d>0)
           {
?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $z; ?>"  name="pagination" id="<?php echo 'pagination' .$z ; ">

<label id="<?php echo 'labelofpagination'.$z; ?>" >

<a href="#" onclick="PaginationLabelClicked(); submit();" >
<?php echo $z; ?>
</a>

    </label>

<?php
            $z++;
            }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your javascript functio you can use the same PHP expression to get the id

```
var id="<?php echo '\"' .$z '\"'; >";
```

or you can have it like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
<?php 
echo("id= $z;");

?>
// -->
</script>
```

to get the id

```
<label id="<?php echo 'labelofpagination'.$z; ?>" >

<a href="#" onclick="PaginationLabelClicked('<?php echo "\"" ."labelofpagination".$z ."\""; ?>'); submit();" >
<?php echo $z; ?>
</a>

    </label>
```

and javascript

```
function PaginationLabelClicked(id){
// you can get the id here...

}
```

Comment: var id="<?php echo 'pagination' .$z ; ?>";   ---------when i use this, then it doesn't runs the javascript.....seems there's some error?

Comment: you can see the genarated javascript in your browser. I have done a mistake. It should be var id="<?php echo '\"' .$z '\"'; >";

Comment: how to know which label is clicked and get the id of the clicked label.? how do i get it? the id is dynamically generated.......and i have 3 labels, 1,2,3 (pageno.s)